# How to open systemd journal files on a Mac

Tags: linux, mac, docker, systemd

I have a list of journal files I copied over from a Linux machine. How do I read these on my Mac?

```
system.journal
system@00057f81c3557a96-72d9555724020539.journal~
system@00057f81c3578ad2-0b1342e26a1084c2.journal~
system@00057f81c35da2ae-1e08ad8d9fb4490e.journal~
system@00057f81c36061ae-4887cabc406c0730.journal~
system@00057f81c3610f02-a2ef88fdd0f7b8b8.journal~
system@00057f81c361f8c9-291d730f905c8c13.journal~
system@00057f81c3622e0e-e11a80ce27e19d78.journal~
system@000581375327165b-1ebd65852c52012b.journal~
system@000581414f1d5717-3fb84669d371cc85.journal~
system@000581414f1eb991-d03234bfd7e97526.journal~
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tool which is used to view the journal files (`journalctl`) is Linux only, so you will need to use virtualization.

[Docker](https://www.docker.com) is probably the simplest tool for this job.

Download & install Docker Desktop and register for a Docker Hub account.

(If your company doesn't allow you to use Docker Desktop, you can use [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima) instead).

Open a Terminal and execute the following:

```
$ docker pull centos/systemd
```

This will pull the `centos/systemd` image from Docker Registry. (You will only need to run this once)

Now you are ready to run `journalctl` inside a container based on this image.

`cd` into the directory where you have the journal files and run:

```
$ docker run -v "$(pwd):/tmp/journal" --rm centos/systemd journalctl --directory="/tmp/journal" --no-pager > journal.log
```

(You might be asked to login to your docker hub account, if so, just run `docker login` first)

What this will do is the following:

1. Share the current directory inside the container (`/tmp/journal`)
2. Run `journalctl` and tell it to concatenate all journal files from `/tmp/journal`, and print the result to the screen
3. Redirect the output into a file called `journal.log`

Now you can use `less` (or even better, [lnav](https://github.com/tstack/lnav)) to open the `journal.log` on your Mac:

```
$ less journal.log
```

Comment: I didn't realize Docker can run Linux software on macOS. Does it perform full system virtualization?

Comment: This response needs updating, as these instructions don't work if using Docker Desktop 4.3.  [https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6073]